# Issue with closing fancybox in IE 8

Tags: jsp, fancybox

On my login success I call the function to close fancybox `setTimeout("window.parent.$.fancybox.close()",4000)enter code here`
...the function works fine on IE 9 but it doesn't close automatically on success in IE8.

Comment: is `enter code here` a typo? .... do you really need to set `window` ... shouldn't be `parent` enough? could you post the complete js code?

Answer (score 0):

Any of these work for me

```
setTimeout( function() { window.parent.$.fancybox.close(); },4000);
setTimeout( window.parent.$.fancybox.close, 4000);
setTimeout( "window.parent.$.fancybox.close()", 4000);
```